# Transferring Data From one DB2 database to other DB2 database

Tags: db2

I have DB2 database installed on one server which contains all the data. Now I am trying to transfer all that data to another DB2 database which is on my local host. I have tried the following steps for this procedure.

1. On the server-

   ```
                 db2 move DB_NAME export
   ```
2. Copied the .lst and all files into my local host.
3. On my local host -

   ```
                 db2 create database DB_NAME
                 db2 -tvf DB_NAME.DDL
                 db2 move DB_NAME import
   ```

   I have succeeded in moving the tables to my local host.

**But somehow data was missing in my local host.**
I am using DB2 version 10.5.1.
Any one please tell me the correct procedure for transferring the data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you using backup/restore for this purpose? Other than that the procedure looks ok (it's db2move not db2 move).

Comment: Hi Lennart, Thanks for your response. Could you please tell me how can I use backup/restore.

Comment: basically you do `db2 "backup db <yourdb> compress"` on the source server, copy the backup file to the target server and do a `db2 restore db <yourdb>`. Check out the documentation for backup/restore for your version.

Comment: Hi Lennart, I have tried this backup and restore process. But I have got the error as 'SQL2514N The RESTORE was not successful. The backup used to restore the database contained a database with a release number that is not compatible with the installed version of the database manager' I am trying to move the data from DB of version 8.1 to DB of version 10.5.1. Is there any other way that I can transfer data?

Comment: Ah ok, that probably wont work. I assumed same platform/version. Are there any error messages during import, example constraint violation? How did you create DB_NAME.DDL, are you sure that if reflects the schema in your v8 database?

Comment: During import I have error messages for some tables like 'The specified table cannot be replaced because another table is dependent on it'[CODE 3201]. I have got the same error message for about 15 tables(Tables for which data is missing). I have created the DDL file from v8 DB by using command "db2 look -db DB_NAME  -e -o DB_NAME.DDL"

Comment: Ok, do you have referential integrity in your database? db2look generates things not necessarily in the correct order. Try creating the schema like: `db2 -l mylog.txt -s +c -tf DB_NAME.DDL` If everything was ok you can commit, if not do a rollback and investigate the error. If you use -s you know you wont have any errors if the skript runs to the end.

Comment: I have tried the above command. It returned me the following error. I do not understand what does this mean.CREATE ALIAS "CN_USER "."ADM_CUSTOMERS" FOR "EN      "."ADM_CUSTOMERS"
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0601N  The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name "CN_USER.ADM_CUSTOMERS" of type "ALIAS".  SQLSTATE=42710

Comment: Drop and recreate your database so that it's empty when you start

Comment: I have tried the command that you have posted before I did import. This time not the data but some tables were missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your initial post, I missed an important point. You are trying to move the data from version 8.x to version 10.5. I've done this in the past and the correct procedure to move the data is to do a migration of the data. This is also what IBM recommends.

To achieve the migration of the database data, you will have to do this:

1. Generate DDL for the database (use **db2look** utility)
2. If you have sequences (export sequence current values, use **select** on **syscat.sequnces**)
3. On version 8.x Server export your data (use **db2 export** command. here I use allways **IXF** format)
4. Create new database on the version 10.5 server (I will also look on new Features or Settings and try to improve the database configuration ... etc. tablespaces, bufferpool can now organize themself automatically)
5. Copy and import your data on the new database (use **db2 load** command. use **reorg** / **runstats** after load to reorganize your data and update table statistics)
6. This step is maybe optional, depends on your database model. If you have referenced keys, the you'll have to do a integrity check (**SET INTEGRITY FOR *<<>>* IMMEDIATE CHECKED**)
7. Update sequences values

I've wrote a script for all these steps. This is not quite easy, but it's also the only way when migrating to another OS.

Comment: there is also a good overview in the DB2 documentation as mavimassi posted. db2move is new to me, simplifies some of my steps.

Answer (score 0):

There are few different ways to move data in db2, here there is a good short overview of the different utilities:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0024482.html

If using db2move, should generate the DDL with db2look, please give some more info of what kind of data was missing.

If moving to a different server like in this case, then should do a backup + redirect restore operation, it is explained here in the Info Center (link may be slow to load) with some good examples:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006249.html

Comment: Hi Mavimassi, I have tried the backup and restore option as well. The thing here is I am trying to move the data from DB of version 8.1 to the DB of version 10.5.1. So when I tried restore command it said 'SQL2514N The RESTORE was not successful. The backup used to restore the database contained a database with a release number that is not compatible with the installed version of the database manager'. About the data that was missing, I have got the table structure imported but not the data inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

**For Single Table  to Move**

db2move dbname export -tn tablename -u username -p password

**For all tables in DB to Move**

db2move dbname export -sn schema -u username -p password

tar , gzip and sftp to target directory

---

unzip , untar

**for loading data to another database**

db2move database load -io replace

Comment: in case you want to load using another schema name ? how do you call db2move

Comment: Hi @Aymanadou, db2move dbname  load -u usernaem -p password -lo replace .